# JSON Data Fuzzy merge

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON data like this

```
{
"array": {

"InvestmentsDeposits": {

            "NAME": "Investments & Deposits",
            "PARENT": [
                {
                    "CONTENT_ID": "Promotions",
                    "DISPLAY_ORDER": 3,
                    "PATH": "/Promotions"
                }
            ]
        },
        "InvestmentsDeposits$$$d": {

            "NAME": "Deposits",

            "PARENT": [
             {
                "CONTENT_ID": "NewPromotion",
                 "text" : "newtext"
              }
            ]
    }

    }
    }
```

I need to search for fuzzy data and merge. For example InvestmentsDeposits and InvestmentsDeposits$$$d need to be merged because it matches closely in name

Need to use javascript for this

For now I can make sure source data will always have $$$d at the end to merge with the target data without $$$d i.e., InvestmentDeposits.

My final merged content should be like this

```
{
    "array": {

    "InvestmentsDeposits": {

                "NAME": "Deposits",
                "PARENT": [
                    {
                        "CONTENT_ID": "NewPromotion",
                        "DISPLAY_ORDER": 3,
                        "PATH": "/Promotions"
                         "text": "newtext"
                    }
                ]
            }

        }
    }
```

any help on this one?

What I have tried so far

```
var json0 = {
```

"InvestmentsDeposits": {

```
            "NAME": "Investments & Deposits",
            "PARENT": [
                {
                    "CONTENT_ID": "Promotions",
                    "DISPLAY_ORDER": 3,
                    "PATH": "/Promotions"
                }
            ]
            }
            };
```

var json1 =

{

"InvestmentsDeposits$$$d": {

```
            "NAME": "Deposits",

            "PARENT": [
             {
                "CONTENT_ID": "NewPromotion",
                 "text" : "newtext"
              }
            ]
    }

    };


    // Merge object2 into object1, recursively
```

$.extend( true, json0, json1 );

I am able to merge the data if i am able to split the InvestmentDeposits and InvestmentDeposits$$$d in to two distinct JSON objects but how to split and move the $$$d data in to another object? to make the jquery extend work

Comment: `"PARENT": ["CONTENT_ID": "NewPromotion",...]` isn't JSON. You don't have JSON, you have something else.

Comment: I fixed the syntax error. Thanks for your help

Comment: See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance What exactly is your question? What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: Syntax errors aside, what have you written so far, and why hasn't it worked?

Comment: I tried jquery deep extend to merge two objects, it works seamelessly if i have two distince json objects but here I have one json object and i have to merge two data using fuzzy match of the name.

Comment: (We meant for you to post your code.)

Comment: Post your code and we (the other users) will help you with it. What we typically *won't* do is write your code for you.

Comment: I added the code i have tried. Sorry I am new to Stackoverflow so kindly bear my ignorance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Object.keys()` to find an object's keys and figure out what data to move over. You can compare the first key with the others to find matches, then remove the keys you just looked at until all of them are gone. Here's an example with a similar object.

```js
    var dat = {
        "InvestmentsDeposits": {
            "NAME": "Investments & Deposits",
            "CONTENT_ID": "Promotions",
            "DISPLAY_ORDER": 3,
            "PATH": "/Promotions"
        }, "InvestmentsDeposits$$$d": {
            "NAME": "Deposits",
            "CONTENT_ID": "NewPromotion",
             "text" : "newtext"
        },
        "NotLikeTheOthers": {
            "Um": "Yeah."
        }
    
    };
    var result = {}; // This will be the merged object
    var keys = Object.keys(dat); // Contains keys
    while(keys.length) {
        var i=1;
        for(; i<keys.length; i++) { // Find matches
            if(keys[0] == keys[i] + '$$$d') { // Match type 1
                result[keys[i]] = dat[keys[i]]; // Copy orig
                for(var j in dat[keys[0]]) { // Replace values
                    result[keys[i]][j] = dat[keys[0]][j];
                }
                keys.splice(i,1);
                keys.shift();
                i = 0;
                break;
            } else if(keys[i] == keys[0] + '$$$d') { // Reverse matched
                result[keys[0]] = dat[keys[0]];
                for(var j in dat[keys[i]]) {
                    result[keys[0]][j] = dat[keys[i]][j];
                }
                keys.splice(i,1);
                keys.shift();
                i = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(i > 0) { // Didn't find a match
            result[keys[0]] = dat[keys[0]];
            keys.shift();
        }
    }
    alert(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Note that `Object.keys()` [requires IE9+](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: I am seeing if there is an alternate way available to prevent this multiple loop. may be using underscore library or lo-dash library?

Comment: I haven't used those libraries, but JavaScript in ES6 has [Array.prototype.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) (only supported by a few browsers so far). There's also [jQuery.each](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/), which does something similar.