# foursquare search api how to search for words with spelling mistakes such as 'strbucks'

Tags: api, search, foursquare

Using the foursquare search api, I would like to search venues close by but to show venues with similar names: starbucks, strbucks, strabucks etc.

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search

Comment: You may have to handle this client side and correct any spelling mistakes before you make the api request.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON Data Fuzzy merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26806474/json-data-fuzzy-merge)